# Renaming disks: from D: to F:

Tags: hard-drive, rename, label, volume-label

How do I rename in Windows 8 disk label from `D:` to `A:`, say ?
I do know how to rename the label from `KINGSTON` to `USB` say, though.

Comment: Use Disk Management;  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Ramhound No. Maybe sometimes in the past. How do I run it under windows 8.1 ?

Comment: The same way you run it on any version of Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive letters are a very different thing from filesystem labels.

Graphical interface: Run `diskmgmt.msc`, right-click the volume and select "Change drive letters and paths".

Command line: Run `diskpart`, select the disk and partition, then use the `assign` command.

Comment: The OS won't let you have two `C:` drive letters. You won't lose data – the drive letters are _not_ written to disk anyway, they're just "virtual" assignments for lack of a better word (they're not the same thing as volume labels!), but you _will_ make Windows unbootable if you change the system volume's drive letter, so don't do that.

Comment: You really mean do not change what now is exactly `C:` is this correct ?

Comment: I mean do not change the drive letter of the volume containing the Windows system files, which is _usually_ `C:`.

Comment: OK. You have said `the drive letters are not written to disk anyway`. Now, I have 2 USB flash disks. On one I have changed `F:` to `G:` and I have left the other unchanged. BUT, the OS (WIndows 8.1) *remembers* the changed `G:` letter and also the unchanged `F:` letter: it just remembers what was changed. This is strange by what you have said in my first line of this comment previously. Where OS remembers this `G:` if not in the flash disk itself ??

Comment: It remembers this within the central system configuration that's kept on the OS disk, of course. For Windows that's the Registry (stored under C:\Windows\System32\Config, accessible through regedit). Can't remember offhand which specific registry location stores drive letter assignments, but they're based on the device's serial number and similar values.